# How to embed images in Angular which lie in another directory than assets?

Tags: html, angular, image, src

I have an Angular Application with the following structure:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGeG1.png)

As you can see, there is a **backend** directory (yellow marked) in which other directories exist, such that the following path is valid: **backend/uploads/users/user123/unnamed.jpg**.

Now I want to use that image in my **app.component.html**

```
<img src="">
```

I tried to put the path in the src-property in different ways but the image is not appearing. How would the src has to look like to use that image in my Angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the angular CLI. Therefore you should put the image in the assets folder. Try again than and it will work.

Like this:

```
<img src="/assets/images/unnamed.jpg">
```

EDIT: I am sorry, did miss out that part. You need to edit the angular.json file for this. Add the path of the backup folder there to the assets. But the backup folder must be in the src folder for this to work. Thats my suggestion for a solution.
So you will be adding "src/backup"

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I have another structure and I have to use images which are not in the assets folder as I explained and my question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is actually feasible. if you want to use an image in an Angular app, it's either an asset and you put it in the assets folder, or it's a resource coming from your backend and you will have to write a proper mechanism to expose the wanted resource, and then use it in your Angular app.

Comment: How would you store the images? Would you store it directly in the MySQL Database as a Blob or would you do something else? I am not quite sure of how the setup should look like. You may are right and my setup is not  feasible. Would you recommend me a setup?